# Does javascript has a similar function with php Concatenation assignment (.=)?

Tags: javascript, php, operator-keyword

```
**PHP String Operators**
(.) Concatenation
(.=) Concatenation assignment
```

Function of a Concatenation assignment below.

```
var1 = "Helo";
var1 .= "World!";
echo var1;
```

The output above would be `Helo World!`

Q: Is there a similar operator like Concatenation assignment in javascript?

thanks.

I am looking for a `Concatenation assignment` not `Assignment Operators`, I ask for it because I do not know what it looks like, how would i know that `+=` there was a concatenation operator? it only says assignment operator. And if you insist that it has a duplicate, then that link would be tittle something like concatenation... not assignment..., because assignment is very far similar than concatenation. Give my points back, I earned it hard!

Comment: would of been quicker to search, than type the question

Comment: Let me clarify this to you. String assignment is `var = "string";`, concatenation is `var = "string"; var +="string2";`.

Comment: diden even follow the link did you, or else you would have seen `test += arr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I believe there is, take a look at the `+=` operator in the javascript console.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript concatenation assignment is `+=` and the corresponding concatenation operator `+`.

```
var var1 = "Hello,";
var1 += " world!";
```

Comment: Hm, I was answering the question that was in the title (more or less, "Does JavaScript have the PHP concatenation assignment .="); someone must have edited it. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), but the concatenation operator is [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) not `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's `+=`

E.g

```
var a = 'hello'
a += ' World1'
>>"hello World1"
```